# Session Expire when no action on windows phone 8.1 silverlight app

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I need to enable a session expire process when there is no action by the user in the application.

I googled and got some links like below http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27771.windows-phone-how-to-implement-session-time-out-in-a-wp-app.aspx

But it is just a countdown for log off. I need to set through actions done on the app. Is there any basic way to do this or need some work around to achieve it?

Please help!! I am new to windows phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "idle" event in Silverlight.  You can create one using the [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx).  You will need to connect common events, such as mouse move, to restart the timer. Something Like This

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" MouseMove="LayoutRoot_MouseMove" MouseEnter="LayoutRoot_MouseEnter"/>
```

Then you need to add your timer Logic in a method and execute that method from these events. Make sure You add your Events in BasePage.